# python 2.7 iterating index error

Tags: python

```
import re

address1 = []
address2 = []
city = []
state = []
zipCode = []

modifiedShipping_address1 = (
    ['#### Example Rd. SE', 'City, OH\xa0#####', 'United States', ''],
    ['### Street Ct', 'Apt B', 'City, SC\xa0#####', 'United States', ''])

for i in modifiedShipping_address1:
    address1.append(i[0])
    if len(i) == 4:
        address2.append('')
        cityIndex = str(i[1]).find(',')
        city.append(i[1][:cityIndex])
        state_re = re.compile(', (.*?)\\xa0')
        state_pat = re.findall(state_re, str(i[1]).strip())
        for i in state_pat:
            state.append(i)
            zip_re = re.compile('\\xa0(.*?)')
            zip_pat = re.findall(zip_re, str(i[1]).strip())
            for i in zip_pat:
                zipCode.append(i)
    else:
        address2.append(i[1])
        cityIndex = str(i[2]).find(',')
        city.append(i[2][:cityIndex])
        state_re = re.compile(', (.*?)\\xa0')
        state_pat = re.findall(state_re, str(i[2]).strip())
        for i in state_pat:
            state.append(i)
        zip_re = re.compile('\\xa0(.*?)')
        # This line throws the exception:
        zip_pat = re.findall(zip_re, str(i[2]).strip())
        for i in zip_pat:
            zipCode.append(i)
    state = state[:]
    zipCode = zipCode[:]

    print state
    print zipCode
```

When run, the code produces this output:

```
['OH']
[]
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "iterating.py", line 37, in <module>
    zip_pat = re.findall(zip_re, str(i[2]).strip())
IndexError: string index out of range
```

How do I go about fixin this? Thank you. I do not understand where indexError is coming from.

Comment: it's not valid python code, please fix the indentation

Comment: Please provide a complete example that demonstrates your problem. The given code has numerous issues that prevent reproduction of your problem: the indentation is still illegal Python; there are strings missing starting or closing quotes; the "\xa#" sequence is an invalid string; address1, address2, city, state and zipCode are undeclared. In addition, it's unclear what text is supposed to be the output from your program and whether it is indeed the complete unmodified output.

Comment: This is still not valid Python code. There is no indentation in front of the address1.append line, and the first line is missing a single quote at `''], [ ### Street Ct'` that makes it impossible to compile. There are other problems beyond that- please make sure *you can run the exact code that is posted*

Comment: If you're wondering why everyone seems to be bothered by the code, read [this](http://sscce.org/) on what a short, self-contained, correct example is.  BTW, you *do* know that not every loop variable need be called `i`, right?.. just saying, is all..

Answer (score 1):

Your problem is that you re-use the variable `i` for every single loop variable. The line of code that throws the exception seems to expect `i` to be the loop variable from the outer loop:

```
for i in modifiedShipping_address1:
```

However, at this point `i` is in fact the last value iterated over by the loop:

```
for i in state_pat:
```

Note that in Python, `for` loops don't introduce a separate scope for their loop variable or contents. It's just another local variable in the function, and there's nothing to reset it after the loop has finished. It just retains its value from the last time around the loop until it is assigned a new value. You can avoid this problem by using different variables for each loop, preferably with more descriptive names than `i`.

---

Please take more care in future to post code that works (or at least, shows the problem that you claim it does), to explain your problem clearly, and to preview your question to make sure that the code appears as you intended. The [SCCEE](http://sscce.org/) page that DSM refers you to is a great guide. You will get better help and fewer downvotes if you follow it.

Answer (score 0):

You are getting that error because the last element of `modifiedShipping_address1` is an empty string.